# Is it possible to append data to a database file using data from different excel sheets?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, xml, vba

I am trying to come up with a solution for this problem. We have about 3 different excel sheets (forms for making reports, not tables of numerical data) which the company is using and I want to know if it is possible to do this:
On filling out the form and clicking on an "Add" macro/button in the excel sheet, the data automatically gets added to a central database file (using either VB, SQL or XML).

Note:

-There are different excel sheets because the formulas are different, but the basic schema (columns) should stay the same.

-I cannot change the excel sheet and make it into an MS Access form because excel can make good graphs that Access can't. So the forms stay as they are. I just need a way to add a feature so the user can click on a button and the data from the form gets added to the database file.

-Any database language, SQL, XML and/or software, MS Access, MySQL will do. If macros are needed, I can also learn to work with VB in excel. I tried googling for solutions, which led me to ADOs, which I have no idea about and it might take a long time for me to learn them.

-There is no central server or user/admin complications involved, all data stays in a single folder on a shared drive.

P.S.: I know this is a vague question, honestly I'm really new to databases (I have just introduced myself to little bit of SQL and am doing this project for my company as it will give me a good learning experience). I just need a nudge in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: you should realize that Excel can talk to access and pull data out of it for use in graphs.

Comment: you can only import excel data in to MySQL for example, what you want to do, no you cant

Comment: @MarcB Are you suggesting I can keep the form and database in Access and add a feature to view graphs for a particular data in excel? I don't know how exactly it's done (I could google for it), I know excel and Access can communicate quite well. Still the issue is that the people here aren't very technologically advanced (worse than me) and my feeling was that it would be a good idea to keep the form and graphs in one place as they simply print it out and send it to the customer. I could ofcourse train them to do something though. Is this the only way it could be done?

Comment: @LeventeNagy I couldn't understand what you said..

Comment: It's not tough in VBA- A quick and easy way to do it, add subroutine to the userform's click button, go to tools->references and add Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 . Then `Dim` a new `ADODB.Connection`, `.Open` the connection object with a connection string (Will vary, something like `Driver=MySQL 5.1; Server=My.Server...etc)`, then make a `ADODB.Recordset`, `.Open` it with parameters for the table name and connection object, call `.Addnew` on the recordset, set its `.Fields('YourFieldName')` equal to the textbox value, then `.Update` the recordset.  That's it, the new record is in the db

Comment: Using "Rob's Answer", create and set variables to the values in your Excel forms or sheets that need to be added to a database.  Then follow Rob's directions.  The code really is simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not tough in VBA- A quick and easy way to do it, add subroutine to the userform's click button, go to tools->references and add Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 . Then Dim a new ADODB.Connection, .Open the connection object with a connection string (Will vary, something like Driver=MySQL 5.1; Server=My.Server...etc), then make a ADODB.Recordset, .Open it with parameters for the table name and connection object, call .Addnew on the recordset, set its .Fields('YourFieldName') equal to the textbox value, then .Update the recordset. That's it, the new record is in the db :)